# Does android has a native amr encoding library in NDK/SDK?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I've come across some 3rd party libraries like opencore-amr and others which allows for raw PCM data to be directly encoded into amr as byte arrays. However these are all software encoders written in C/C++ and borrows from many sources.

Is there a **official** Amr library for android bundled in NDK or SDK where you can convert PCM to amr byte by byte?

Answer (score 0):

There is such a component within the system, that you can access via the MediaCodec API. You can access it via Java since Android 4.1 (which you need to call via JNI if you want to use it in native code) or directly as native API since Android 5.0. This internally basically is the same code as opencore-amr, but wrapped up as a generic decoder/encoder component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both AMR-NB and AMR-WB are [supported in MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core)

Comment: I see but it seems to rely on container and implicit capture rather than providing an explicit interface to the library or implementation

Comment: Not at all. You pass a ByteBuffer containing your input raw PCM data, and receive a ByteBuffer containing the output encoded AMR frame. It's asynchronous though, so it's a little more convoluted than the internal software codec implementation itself, but this also allows the same API to be used for e.g. HW codecs.

Comment: MediaCodec api is only supported for API16 and above. I don't think support libs have those. so need to watchout if you target the older devices